# How can I play audiobooks from current position (where it stopped) in android media player?

Tags: java, android

I am working with android application where I want play audiobooks from current position of books (eg:0:04/6:35 ) now I want play it  and should start from 0:05 not from starting like 0:00.How can I achieve this please anyone help me out to get a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have paused it:

```
Mediaplayer.pause();
length = Mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();  
Mediaplayer.seekTo(length);
Mediaplayer.start();
```

or if you want to start directly from the very very start:

```
length = 4 * 1000; //milliseconds, starts at 0:04
Mediaplayer.seekTo(length);
Mediaplayer.start();
```